# Have two forms, want one of them to be displayed as if it was inside the other

Tags: html

The title might be confusing... the problem is the following:

I'm making a register page for a web site, so i have the usual things like nick, email, name, surname, date of birth, profile image, etc.
As far as i know it's not possible to make only one form to handle files(profile image) and text at the same time, so i had to make two forms, one of them has the profile image and the other form has the rest(all the fields and a button to complete the registration). The problem is that i want the profile image form to be displayed between the date of birth and the finish button(which are both in the other form...).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: How does this involve the Java programming language? Why the [tag:java] tag? Is there a Java back-end involved here that you're not mentioning? Or do you really mean to tag this for [tag:javascript]? You are clear on the difference of course, right?

Comment: Why can't one form handle files and text simultaneously?

Comment: If you must use 2 forms then declare 2 forms one after the other. And then using CSS positioning (e.g. position:absolute), you can display one form as if it was inside the other one.

Comment: Hovercraft: this issue doesn't actually involve java, sorry, i got confused.
Vulcan: I thought that could not be done, if it's possible please tell me how.
gparis: Thanks, i will study and try this.

Answer (score 0):

A form can contain a mix of file input control and other input controls. When the form from below will be submitted the file content and the textInput value will be received by the server.

```
<form action="UploadUrl" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="text" id="textInput" name="textInput" value="zzz"/>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that in the servlet i do:
request.getParameter("fileInput") and it returns null... that's because of the enctype="multipart/form-data", if i delete that line all works fine.

Comment: Use the FileUpload library http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-a-servlet.html